# Finding invalid emails with spaces using Regex

Tags: regex, pcre, email-validation

I have scanned multiple files as pdf and I now want to extract emails from those files using regex. But the PDF sometimes has spaces in between words as it's image to text interpretation is not perfect. It is not possible to redo the scans as I no longer have the documents in paper.

For example these are the possibilities:

```
example.email@gmail.com
example.email@g mail.com
example.email@ gmail.com
example.email @ gmail.com
example.email @ gmail .com
example.email @gmail .com
example.email @gm ail .com
example.email @ gmail . com
exa mple.email@gmail.com
exa mple.email @gmail.com
exa mple.email @ gmail.com
exa mple.email @gmail .com
exa mple.email @ gmail .com
exa mplemail @ gmail .com
```

I have tried multiple regex expressions but my knowledge of regex is too limited to find all the solutions.

I used the General Email Regex from http://emailregex.com/ and added spaces.

```
(?:[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-zA-z0-9 ](?:[a-zA-Z0-9- ]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-z0-9](?:[a-zA-z0-9-]*[a-zA-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-zA-z0-9-]*[a-zA-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])
```

This solutions only matches to 4 of the possibilities.

Any suggestions to find more of the emails? Partial solutions are also welcome since I can add them to the results.

Note: The pdf does not contain only the emails. So a line of text could look like this: "email: example.email @ gmail .com?\"

Comment: Please specify language/technology you're using in tags

Comment: I'm using the program Agent Ransack what is using the Perl or Classic syntax

Comment: I believe it is called https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions

Comment: What do you want if your string is "You can reach me at ikegami@example.com"? Or is that impossible?

Comment: @ikegami According to the documentation it uses Perl: https://help.mythicsoft.com/agentransack/en/regular_expressions.htm

Comment: It says nothing of the kind. It's definitely not Perl, so I removed the tag. It doesn't seem to be PCRE either, seeing as it links to Boost's documentation, and the docs don't appear to be documenting PCRE. But one could say the documented engine is compatible with (an ancient version of) PCRE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
/^[\w. -]++@[\w. -]++$/gm
```

Comment: This solution works with the given possibilities. But it sadly doesn't work with the example line: "email: example.email @ gmail .com?\"

Comment: It may be corrected:    `/^[\w.: -]++@[\w. -]++$/gm`